# Array rank transform giving unexpected result

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Solution:
    def arrayRankTransform(self, nums):
        x = sorted(list(collections.Counter(nums)))
        for i in range(len(x)):
            for c in nums:
                if c == x[i]:
                    nums[nums.index(c)] = i+1
        return print(nums)
```

```
myArray = [2,-11,24,15,26,-31,-48,-49,22,37,-36]
```

returns:

```
[6, 5, 9, 7, 10, 4, 6, 1, 8, 11, 3]
```

I'm at a complete loss as to how -48 got ranked a 6.

Comment: please read how to [create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please post your code/results as _text_ in the question, not as images.

Comment: Can you explain what output you are trying to achieve?  I'm not sure I understand what this `arrayRankTransform` is supposed to be doing.  Why are you using `collections.Counter` when there are no duplicate values in your `myArray`?

Comment: Hint: `-48` is the 2nd smallest number, and it ended up being assigned the same result as `2`. Both got a rank of `6`. Coincidence?

Comment: It does not solve the problem in your code, but just in case you don't know, you can use the functions from both `scipy` and `pandas`: `from scipy import stats; stats.rankdata(myArray)` and `import pandas as pd; pd.Series(myArray).rank()`, respectively.

Comment: Why are you looping over _both_ the sorted and original lists?  What are you trying to do?  I think you are over-complicating the solution.  Also, your issue seems to be that you are _modifying_ `nums` as you are looping over it (and the sorted version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are looping over `nums` and inside this loop, you are also modifying `nums`.

So, in your loop, when you are checking if the values, your `nums` is no longer the original list.

You are slightly over-complicating the solution here, you don't need two `for` loops, you can do this simply using list comprehension.

```
x = sorted(list(collections.Counter(nums)))
return [x.index(v)+1 for v in nums]
```

Comment: woah I didn't know about list comprehension its so simple and clean. Thanks for showing me that I just started playing around with python a few weeks ago so I still have a lot to learn.

Comment: @frslefsekiro List comprehension (as well as dict and set comprehension) are one of my favorite things about python.  Once you learn them, you'll be using them everywhere :)